# Qual a diferença entre Count() e Length?

Tags: c#, array, .net, vb.net, linq

No .NET, temos a propriedade `Array.Length` que vem do tipo `System.Array` e funciona na maioria dos tipos de coleção. Também temos o `Enumerable.Count()` que é presente como uma função de extensão dentro da namespace `System.Linq`.

Eu notei que ambas fazem o mesmo papel e retornam o mesmo resultado para coleções idênticas. Então, qual a diferença entre os dois? Qual devo usar e qual devo evitar?

> Uma dúvida adicional: é verdade que o `Count()` itera todos os itens da coleção para contar a quantia de elementos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Além do fato do [`Length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length?view=net-8.0) ser nativo do tipo e o `Count()` ser de um tipo auxiliar, e ainda, o primeiro ser uma propriedade (que não deixa de ser uma função disfarçada) e o segundo ser (explicitamente) uma função, há uma diferença implícita não obrigatória.

Quando escolhemos uma propriedade geralmente queremos fazer algo que apenas pega um valor com complexidade constante, ou seja, leva sempre o mesmo tempo para obter sem importar o tamanho da coleção de dados a analisar.

Isto é possível porque de alguma forma essa informação já existe e não precisa fazer nenhuma operação para obter. O `array` guarda a quantidade de elementos da coleção então fica fácil. Em outras coleções esse número seria mantido atualizado em cada operação que mude o tamanho da coleção. No `array` nem precisa porque o tamanho é fixo depois de criado.

Esta propriedade foi criada nesse tipo nativo da linguagem e do CLR.

Outras coleções de dados pode não ser possível obter esse número em tempo constante, porque pode ser que nem seja possível determiná-lo à priori. Há muitos casos que é preciso fazer uma contagem para saber quantos elementos ela tem.

Então uma função foi escolhida porque ela tem potencial para ter uma complexidade logarítmica, linear, a mais comum, ou até pior, quadrática por exemplo (raríssimo). Como pode demorar para executar uma função é mais adequada que uma propriedade.

Claro que se for possível fazer em tempo constante (O(1)) será feito. Mas para isto a função precisa ser nativa do tipo, ela precisa conhecer o detalhe de implementação do tipo. O [`Enumerable.Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) não pode saber desse detalhe, então ele sempre fará uma contagem em tempo linear (O(n)) já que serve para qualquer tipo enumerável, até aquele que não tem um tamanho definido e só pode ser contado.

Obviamente que existe uma otimização em coleções que possuem a propriedade [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection.count?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que não está na pergunta mas que existe também, então se o tipo a tiver ela será usada sem precisar fazer a contagem.

Apesar dessa otimização manter a complexidade constante ela é bem mais lenta, chega ser centenas de vezes, porém constante.

Eu sempre falo que o LINQ não deveria ser tão natural assim como as pessoas gostam. Ele tende ser bastante menos eficiente que outra forma, quando ele está disponível.

A ideia da contagem ocorre com um padrão de projeto chamado [Iterator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#C#_and_other_.NET_languages).

O uso do [`Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é bem melhor que usar um `Count() > 0`. Ele evita ter que varrer toda a coleção para descobrir se é 0 ou mais que isso.

Aí vem a pergunta: por que existem propriedades diferentes com a mesma informação?

A ideia de tamanho indica algo fixo e a ideia de contagem algo que pode ter o tamanho variável, ainda que não varie de fato. Poderia existir só o `Count` mas no começo os tipos mais básicos da linguagem, como [`array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e [`string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.length?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), usaram `Length` e as coleções mais abstratas não podiam usar isso com algo que tinha tamanho potencialmente variável.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).